# jQuery Ajax Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write a jQuery Ajax function, to reduce the amount of code in the page because the script is called a few times in the page. I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the code i have:

```
var loadURL = $(this).attr('href');
function load(){
$.ajax({
    url: loadURL,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    data: {
        delay: 4
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#load').html(data)
    }
    });
return false;}
$('#one').click(function(){ load(); });
$('#two').click(function(){ load(); });
$('#three').click(function(){ load(); });
<a href="one.php" id="one">Two</a>
<a href="two.php" id="two">Two</a>
<a href="three.php" id="three">Two</a>
```

can anyone guide me here please?

Comment: where do you have this line of code ??var loadURL = $(this).attr('href');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the way you are getting href is wrong

```
function load(item){
var loadURL = $(item).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url: loadURL,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    data: {
        delay: 4
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#load').html(data)
    }
    });
return false;}
$('#one').click(function()
{ 
load($(this)); 
return false; //you should mention return false here
});
```

Comment: this almost works for me. the information is injected into the container, but the function does not return false, and the page is still loaded. Thanks for all of the help. i really appreciate this.

Comment: @mcbeav , return false should definetly kill the default behavior of href , i am 100% sure

Comment: @mcbeav , see updated answer you should have return false in the click event....handler

Comment: I actually tried that, and for whatever reason, the function no longer works. Nothing happens when i click the link.

Comment: what if i changed the function to use .ajaxSetup()

Comment: @mcbeav , see if you have syntax errors, open firebug??console while you click that

Comment: ah, mispelled the actual url, thanks for the help i really appreciate it. Thanks again. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that you can [define your own jQuery functions if you wish](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/basil/archive/2008/09/22/defining-your-own-functions-in-jquery.aspx)..